# Access User Meta Data on User Registration in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to carry out a few functions when a user registers on a wordpress site.  I have created a module for this which carries out the following function:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'tml_new_user_registered' );

function tml_new_user_registered( $user_id ) {
    //wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
    //wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $subscription_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, "subscribe_to_newsletter", TRUE);
    if($subscription_value == "Yes") {
        //include("Subscriber.Add.php");    
    }


    echo "<pre>: ";
    print_r($user_info);
    print_r($subscription_value);
    echo "</pre>";

    exit;
}
```

But it seems that i am not able to access any user meta data as at the end of this stage none of it is stored.

Any ideas how i execute a function once Wordpress has completed the whole registration process of adding meta data into the relevant tables too?

I attempted to use this:

```
add_filter('user_register ','tml_new_user_registered',99);
```

But with no luck unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I read at the [action reference api page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) that the user id is passed as `user ID`.  Try substituting your `$user_id` for `$user_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the user metadata is available at the point where this action hook is triggered. From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

"Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this action is triggered. For example, nickname is in the database but first_name and last_name are not (as of 3.9.1). The password has already been encrypted when this action is triggered."