# How can I get some specific user meta data and check afterwards with condition or so on for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Below are the User meta information that I got by the following code ...

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id );
print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
die();
```

What I need is that I have to check the payment gateway value for a specific need if it's "paymill" or not and then I also need other two values for the "sector" and "branche" to store in variables for reasons.

How can I get only those and check. I'm using "Leaky Paywall Plugin".

Results:

```
Array
(
.......
[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_level_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7.99
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_description] => Array
    (
        [0] => DWN Payment Form (production - uid : 35604)
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_plan] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_created] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2016-12-15 12:54:22
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_subscriber_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_payment_gateway] => Array
    (
        [0] => paymill
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_payment_status] => Array
    (
        [0] => active
    )

[dwn_paywall_trial_status] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_email_verlagsangebot] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_branche] => Array
    (
        [0] => immobilien-und-logistik
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_sector] => Array
    (
        [0] => management-und-unternehmensentwicklung
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_firma] => Array
    (
        [0] => Consequatur est ex laboris ipsam at voluptatem ipsam tempore
    )

[address_street] => Array
    (
        [0] => Obcaecati voluptas atque libero dolore corporis omnis beatae
    )

[address_number] => Array
    (
        [0] => 90
    )

[address_postcode] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
    )

[address_city] => Array
    (
        [0] => Deleniti qui cupiditate laudantium fugiat unde enim maiores reprehenderit est
    )

[address_land] => Array
    (
        [0] => frankreich
    )

[genre] => Array
    (
        [0] => herr
    )

[birthdate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1931-08-10 00:00:00
    )

[_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_expires] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2017-01-15 23:59:59
    )
.......
)
```

Comment: I got the solution already. Thanks

Comment: Care to share the solution as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just have taken the followings data that I need for my further work...

```
$payment_paymill = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_payment_gateway", TRUE);                                                                                                                                                                                  
    $sector = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_sector", TRUE);                   
    $branche = get_user_meta( $user_id, "_issuem_leaky_paywall_live_branche", TRUE);
```

helpful: [Access User Meta Data on User Registration in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042394/access-user-meta-data-on-user-registration-in-wordpress?rq=1)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible set roles by category, in which one the user can access freely (using leaky paywall)?